# Align button in bottom without use position:absolute

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this sample:

[link](https://jsfiddle.net/bryg2jp7/)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div class="product-group">
  <div class="product-wrapper">
      <div class="product-img">
          <img src="http://s1.busteco.ro/cristi/rbb/media/catalog/product/cache/3/small_image/210x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/images/catalog/product/placeholder/small_image.jpg" >
      </div>
      <div class="product-details">
           <h3 class="product-name">
                        <a href="http://s1.busteco.ro/cristi/rbb/b2b/better-than-a-tie-bundle.html" title="&quot;Better Than a Tie&quot; Father’s Day Gift Bundle">
                            "Better Than a Tie" Father’s Day Gift Bundle                        </a>
                    </h3>
                    <div class="product-description">
                       <p class="availability">
                            Release date:    
                            07/26/2016                        </p>
                        <a href="http://s1.busteco.ro/cristi/rbb/b2b/better-than-a-tie-bundle.html" class="button view">View product</a>

                    </div>
      </div>

  </div>
  <div class="product-wrapper">
      <div class="product-img">
          <img src="http://s1.busteco.ro/cristi/rbb/media/catalog/product/cache/3/small_image/210x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/images/catalog/product/placeholder/small_image.jpg" >
      </div>
      <div class="product-details">
           <h3 class="product-name">
                        <a href="http://s1.busteco.ro/cristi/rbb/b2b/better-than-a-tie-bundle.html" title="&quot;Better Than a Tie&quot; Father’s Day Gift Bundle">
                            "Better Than a Tie" Father’s Day Gift <br> Bundle"Better Than a Tie" Father’s Day  <br>  Gift Bundle "Better Than a Tie" <br>Father’s Day  Gift Bundle "Better Than a Tie" <br>                       </a>
                    </h3>
                    <div class="product-description">
                       <p class="availability">
                            Release date:    
                            07/26/2016                        </p>
                        <a href="http://s1.busteco.ro/cristi/rbb/b2b/better-than-a-tie-bundle.html" class="button view">View product</a>

                    </div>
      </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
.product-group{
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;    }

.product-wrapper{
    background:#f0f0f0;
    margin:35px 0;
    padding:8px 8px 10px 8px;
    }

    .product-name { margin:0; font-size:1em; font-weight:normal; }

    .product-wrapper .product-details p.availability {
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: capitalize;}
```

Plase view the button "view product",It must be in the bottom always, regardless of content.

At this time, the buttons are not aligned as they should. Their position is bottom: 0

How can you do this without using position: absolute?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you not use absolute positioning? Is fixed a proper solution if absolute is not?

Comment: In the bottom of what - each product container? The page?

Comment: in  bottom div "product wrapper"

Comment: Did you miss to post .button and .view CSS classes?

Comment: This element I want to align bottom "class="button view"

Comment: but why don;t you want to use posititon:absolute ? what's the hold up ? with your html structure...position:absolute it's the best and maybe only way to do it

Comment: because I want to see if you can and otherwise I do know with absolute position

Comment: If it's simply for a brain exercize - yes, there are other ways: You could use flexboxes, javascript, or tables, for example. Absolute positioning is the way to go here, though, for both straight-forwardness and simplicity, as all other methods require a lot more effort.

Comment: ok I want to see flexboxes method ... can you help me please?

Comment: The answer in the dupe has multiple flexbox methods for aligning an element to the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to achieve what you want using `flex`.  This way, any wrappers on the same line will be the same height, and the product links will all line up. (Use full page link on snippet below)

```css
.product-group {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}
.product-wrapper {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  margin: 35px 0;
  padding: 8px 8px 10px 8px;
  display: flex;             /* make each wrapper flex*/
  flex-direction: column;    /* stack inner elements into a column */
}
.product-name {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.product-wrapper .product-details p.availability {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  /* make this take the empty space and push the link to the bottom */
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.product-description,
.product-details {
  /* make these flex and stretch to fit their parents remaining space */
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-group">
  <div class="product-wrapper">
    <div class="product-img">
      <img src="http://s1.busteco.ro/cristi/rbb/media/catalog/product/cache/3/small_image/210x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/images/catalog/product/placeholder/small_image.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="product-details">
      <h3 class="product-name"><a href="http://s1.busteco.ro/cristi/rbb/b2b/better-than-a-tie-bundle.html" title="&quot;Better Than a Tie&quot; Father’s Day Gift Bundle">"Better Than a Tie" Father’s Day Gift Bundle</a></h3>
      <div class="product-description">
        <p class="availability">
          Release date: 07/26/2016</p>
        <a href="http://s1.busteco.ro/cristi/rbb/b2b/better-than-a-tie-bundle.html" class="button view">View product</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-wrapper">
    <div class="product-img">
      <img src="http://s1.busteco.ro/cristi/rbb/media/catalog/product/cache/3/small_image/210x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/images/catalog/product/placeholder/small_image.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="product-details">
      <h3 class="product-name"><a href="http://s1.busteco.ro/cristi/rbb/b2b/better-than-a-tie-bundle.html" title="&quot;Better Than a Tie&quot; Father’s Day Gift Bundle">"Better Than a Tie" Father’s Day Gift <br> Bundle"Better Than a Tie" Father’s Day  <br>  Gift Bundle "Better Than a Tie" <br>Father’s Day  Gift Bundle "Better Than a Tie" <br> </a></h3>
      <div class="product-description">
        <p class="availability">
          Release date: 07/26/2016</p>
        <a href="http://s1.busteco.ro/cristi/rbb/b2b/better-than-a-tie-bundle.html" class="button view">View product</a>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```